# How to change color text up to a colon, and then change text after the colon to a different color

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to color text in a word document (code snippets) red up until the colon, then after the colon it needs to be blue until a comma or ending paren in each line (or selection).

I've been using "selection" and trying to use the move function to start up with the blue. But I'm new to VBA and all the tutorials are confusing to me as to how to tell it when to start and stop with specific formatting.

I found this that I thought might be a helpful bit, but when I put a comma in instead of a _ VB was unhappy with me.

```
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, _ 
Extend:=wdExtend
```

Comment: The underline is merely to allow the code to break to a new line, rather than being on one line. You might investigate MoveEndUntil...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by each line you refer to paragraphs in word then the simple code may serve your purpose

```
Sub TestColorPara()
Dim Para As Paragraph, Rng As Range, ColonAt As Long, CommaAt As Long

For Each Para In Selection.Paragraphs
Ln = Para.Range.Characters.Count
    If Ln > 1 Then
    ColonAt = InStr(1, Para.Range.Text, ":")
        If ColonAt > 0 Then
        Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=Para.Range.Start, End:=Para.Range.Start + ColonAt)
        Rng.Font.Color = wdColorRed

        CommaAt = InStr(ColonAt, Para.Range.Text, ",")
        CommaAt = IIf(CommaAt > 0, CommaAt, Ln - 1)
        Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=Para.Range.Start + ColonAt, End:=Para.Range.Start + CommaAt)
        Rng.Font.Color = wdColorBlue
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Tested to achieve what I understand as your requirement.

Comment: That works BEAUTIFULLY, I only need the colon and comma to remain the original color (not red or blue). This answered a dozen questions I had about VB thank you!

Comment: You made my day